# Unable to see the values set in EXTRA_TITLE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-intent-chooser

I am building an app say Tx , which call's the createChooser using the below code.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent("com.myapplication.test");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Sharing ..");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Shared from Tx app.." );
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Choose the app ..")));
```

I have also built few app's with below in their androidManfiest.xml files.

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.myapplication.test" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

When Tx's createChooser is called, I am able to see all the app's where -com.myapplication.test is present & also the title as - Choose the app .. . However, I am not able to see the EXTRA_TITLE which is set to "Sharing ..".

Is there any way I can show this in the chooser? any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What device & API level are you testing on?  Because I tested your code & it displayed the title at the top properly.

Comment: I am using Samsung Mobile Phone , Android 11

Comment: Interesting. Because I am Samsung M51 with Android 11. & it does display the title in the chooser.

Comment: ok, let me try it in a different phone .

Comment: I tried with a different phone . I am getting Choose the app .. in the title , but not 
Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Sharing .." , can you please share your screenshot if possible ?

Comment: This is the chooser image from Samsung M51: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/23383818?key=1a9c478bd83807325fd46eee01ef6056

Comment: thank you for sharing your screenshot . I will check again ... looks to me there is some issue with the binary version too !!